# How do I loop over pandas Data frame to create adjacency list?

Tags: python, pandas, nodes, graph-algorithm

I have functions that create an adjacency list:

```
adj_list = {}
list1 = []
  
def add_node(node):
  if node not in list1:
    list1.append(node)
  else:
    print(f'Node {node} already added')

def add_edge(node, target,weight):
  temp= []
  if node in list1 and target in list1:
    temp.append(target,weight)
    adj_list[node] = temp

  elif node in adj_list:
    temp.extend(adj_list[node])
    temp.append(target,weight)
    adj_list[node] = temp 
  else:
    print('Node does not exit')
```

but I can only add nodes and edges manually like this:

```
add_node(0)
add_node(1)

add_edge(0,1,2)
add_edge(1,2,2)
```

But I have a relatively large graph, and I can't add them all by hand, so I put sample graph data in a data frame:

| node | target | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 0 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |

Looping over `df['node']` works:

```
for i in df['node']:
  add_node(i)
```

but I can't find a way to do the same for `add_edges`

So what I am trying to build is a function that takes a data frame and returns a graph, like this:

```
# graph
0  --->  [[1, 2]]
1  --->  [[2, 2]]
2  --->  [[3, 4]]
3  --->  [[0, 5], [4, 3]]
4  --->  [[0, 1]]

# adj_list
{0: [[1, 2]], 1: [[2, 2]], 2: [[3, 4]], 3: [[0, 5], [4, 3]], 4: [[0, 1]]}
```

Also, I know about libraries like networkx but I need to implement this from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do the same for `add_edge`, by looping over each row of the dataframe using [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    add_edge(row.node, row.target, row.weight)
```